# c# 2D array bubblesort

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, bubble-sort

I am trying to perform a bubble sort on a 2D array, sorting by the third index (the integer)

```
string[,] edges = new string[,] { {"A", "B", "2"},
                                          {"A", "C", "3"},
                                          {"A", "E", "10"},
                                          {"B", "C", "5"},
                                          {"B", "D", "10"},
                                          {"C", "D", "2"},
                                          {"D", "E", "5"},
                                          {"E", "B", "3"}
                                        };
```

I get an IndexOutOfRangeException on IF statenent of the sort code

```
        string[] temp = {};

        //sort edges and add them to sortedEdges - using bubblesort
        for (int i = 0; i < edges.Length - 1; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < edges.Length - 1; j++){
                if (Int32.Parse(edges[i, 2]) > Int32.Parse(edges[i + 1, 2])){
                    //make a swap
                    //put array record i into temp holder
                    temp[0] = edges[i, 0];
                    temp[1] = edges[i, 1];
                    temp[2] = edges[i, 2];

                    //copy i + 1 into i
                    edges[i, 0] = edges[i + 1, 0];
                    edges[i, 1] = edges[i + 1, 1];
                    edges[i, 2] = edges[i + 1, 2];

                    //copy temp into i + 1
                    edges[i + 1, 0] = temp[0];
                    edges[i + 1, 1] = temp[1];
                    edges[i + 1, 2] = temp[2];

                }
            }
        }
```

My question is, how do I fix this so that the array "edges" is filled with the rows, ordered by the third column?

Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Side note: `"3"` is a string not "the integer". You really should be using proper structure to store data instead of row in an essentially untyped array.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I used the word integer just to point out which field I wanted to sort. In the IF statement I do convert it to integer.

I realise this could be done better but my main aim is to get the thing working in a clear way.

Comment: It seems that people didn't like my question? philipxy thanks for the link was the problem the code or the general nature of the question? Thanks for any feedback, I will endeavor to ask better questions in the future should the need arise.

Comment: Give input data, output data, expected output data, any error messages, compiler, system you are running on, etc. Ie *everything that affects what your program is doing and that tell us what you want it to do*. Per the help links. PS: You must use @ to contact someone who isn't an asker, an answerer or the only commenter on your post so far. (Search about stackexchange notifications.)

Comment: @user4416058 You should have simplified your sample to just 2d array (n x 1) of integers - all logic would be the same, but readers would not feel pain by looking at code like `Int32.Parse(edges[i + 1, 2])`. Such rewrite would also make sample almost 3 times shorter. Misuse of arrays to represent classes is generally not welcome and may invite downvotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED v-3**

The problem was in `Length` for such defined table which in your case was `24` because it seems to count all the elements in both dimensions.
Please try the following code:

```
string[] temp = new string[3];

for (int i = 0; i < edges.GetLength(0) - 1; i++){
    int j;
    j = 0;
    for (; j < edges.GetLength(0) - 1; j++){

        if (Int32.Parse(edges[j, 2]) > Int32.Parse(edges[j + 1, 2])){
            //make a swap
            //put array record j into temp holder
            temp[0] = edges[j, 0];
            temp[1] = edges[j, 1];
            temp[2] = edges[j, 2];

            //copy j + 1 into j
            edges[j, 0] = edges[j + 1, 0];
            edges[j, 1] = edges[j + 1, 1];
            edges[j, 2] = edges[j + 1, 2];

            //copy temp into j + 1
            edges[j + 1, 0] = temp[0];
            edges[j + 1, 1] = temp[1];
            edges[j + 1, 2] = temp[2];

        }
    }
}
```

You can find (updated) working example here: **https://dotnetfiddle.net/FQs4OA**

Comment: Thanks, but I still get the same error.

Comment: That's more or less the entire code that does anything. I don't understand why I get the error either. I'm going to keep working on it.

Comment: Thanks, did that work for you? I got the same error. I have narrowed it down slightly, the out of bounds is on the second part of the comparison.

Int32.Parse(edges[i + 1, 2])

Comment: Thank you! That seems to prevent the error now I can get some real work done. Thanks again.

Comment: @user4416058 note that proper way of getting length by each dimiension is `Array.GetLength(dimension)` - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/832655/how-do-i-iterate-rows-and-columns-of-a-multidimensional-array

Comment: Thank you very much @Alexei for your remark - I've just edited the answer. Regards.